# Why sometimes my question shows "modified by", but the content hasn't been edited?

Tags: discussion, editing

Why sometimes my question shows "modified by", but the content hasn't been edited?

For example, my most recent question shows in the list that it has been modified by a user.

[image: Modified by]

But in fact, when I check the question, there's no sign of any editing.

[image]

Is it because the edit is awaiting peer review? But I thought OP would get notified of those to-be-reviewed edits and get to approve them. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, it is because there is a deleted answer that you don't have enough reputation to see.